# How to detect Console/Stack drift working with AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, infrastructure-as-code

As it says it on the tin, I am looking for a suggestions or advise for managing those pesky Console changes that may occur when working in IaC with CDK. Anything that introduces drift which CloudFormation is so nice at detecting.
There must be a way CDK (or something else) can get to what CfN drift detection finds, right ?

To direct the ideas a bit more, in the long run I will be aiming to have the deployment of CDK stacks through GitHub on merge. But starting off locally for now.

Expected `cdk diff` to give me something, but quickly realised that was only for local diffs.
Saw a suggestion to try `cdk deploy --no-execute` but that returns everything as healthy.

Comment: You can use `CloudFormationStackDriftDetectionCheck`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CloudFormationStackDriftDetectionCheck` to check whether your CloudFormation stacks' actual configuration differs, or has drifted, from its expected configuration.

Example:-

```
// Topic to which compliance notification events will be published
const complianceTopic = new sns.Topic(this, 'ComplianceTopic');

const rule = new config.CloudFormationStackDriftDetectionCheck(this, 'Drift');
rule.onComplianceChange('TopicEvent', {
  target: new targets.SnsTopic(complianceTopic),
});
```

Ref:-
[class CloudFormationStackDriftDetectionCheck (construct)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_config.CloudFormationStackDriftDetectionCheck.html)

Comment: I'd imagine this doesn't tie in directly with CDK, would it ? 
Goal is when I want to redeploy the same stack, where a change has been made to the resource in console (introducing drift), I need something to raise that to the deployer.

Comment: @DimitriosK, This class `CloudFormationStackDriftDetectionCheck` construct is implemented in AWS CDK only, I didn't understand what you by mean "I'd imagine this doesn't tie in directly with CDK". There are some methods associated with this class like applyRemovalPolicy, onEvent, onComplianceChange, onReEvaluationStatus etc which you explore to use as per your needs. Please read the doc:-https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_config.CloudFormationStackDriftDetectionCheck.html#example

Comment: What I meant by that is, that I would need to set up logic to check the status of the "CloudFormationStackDriftDetectionCheck" outcome (SNS, SQS or wherever) I guess. Like "If CloudFormation drift is detected when a CDK deployment is ran, stop the deployment and output something".

In even simpler terms, I am asking if we can do something similar to what Terraform does with states.
Your answer gives me something to think about, but also asking if people do the classic resource state tracking/drift detection we expect from IaC in CDK also (not in the AWS Console that is)